# Android: What is the Result of using "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"?

Tags: android, android-intent

If I had an stack history of A -> B -> C and activity C wants to start activity A using the flag:

```
 FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?
```

would this create a new stack that would wipe the previous stack? Such that pressing back from C would exit the app?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @dominicoder So I tried using "adb shell dumpsys activity activities" to print out the activities, based on the massive text that came out and using CTRL + F, it seems like the activities in the stack are destroyed when combining these two flags